# Compilation errors when using Gradle task

Tags: jar, gradle

I'm currently trying to **move my build process based on Ant to Gradle**.

For some of my Java projects, I need to **generate a jar file**. This jar file
will be use by other Java project. 
When I use Ant to create the Jar file (via the **Ant Jar task**), it's OK.

But When I try to use Gradle, for some projects, I've got some compilation errors like:

> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."

The --stacktrace option give no additional informations. So, Gradle 
compilation show me that there are some errors in my code.
But this same code (jar by the Ant jar task) is currently used by 20 or more other projects and all it's OK.

**Gradle seems to be a great Build tool, so I would like to understand why this (compilation errors) happening when I use Gradle Jar task (more accurately when I use the compileJava task).**

Thank in advance for any help or explanations.

Comment: What does your gradle build file look like, what are you invoking, and what is the actual result (ie. which compilation errors are you getting). It seems like you have not declared all dependencies.

Comment: I'm quite sure that all dependencies in my build.gradle is ok because I use the same as with the Ant build. But gradle compileJava tell me that there is a problem with the code. For example,
 `error: type argument MyPanel is not within bounds of type-variable T
;
  private void setDefaultValue(MyList<MyPanel> ps) {
                                     
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends APanel<?> declared in class MyList` 

But with the Ant jar task, all It's OK. Or maybe, this ant task ignore compile errors and create the jar without any warnings.

Comment: If the ant build.xml only creates a jar, that means that something else is compiling it, else ant would also fail on this. `gradle compileJava` does not create a jar, but compiles classes. `gradle jar` creates a jar.

Comment: The difference in behavior could come from compiling with different JDK versions. Sometimes lower JDK versions don't complain about Generics related code although they should. By default, Gradle will compile with the JDK version shown in `gradle -v` (under `JRE`). Also check that compiler source and target version settings are the same. In Gradle, they are controlled by the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` properties (e.g. `sourceCompatibility = 1.5`).

Comment: @Peter I've tried your solution but I still have the same compilation errors. Also, I tried to use the same compiler version for Ant and Gradle (via Eclipse). But the result is the same: with Ant, it works fine but with Gradle, I've got compilation errors (even if I change the source and target compatibility in the build.gradle). Moreover, I tried another thing: create the jar lib manually (the project in Eclipse workspace -> Export.. -> Jar file).    As with Ant, no compilation errors (only warnings but none of them concerning the previous generics problems).

Comment: I won't comment here anymore as you already moved the discussion to http://forums.gradle.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of investigation, I found the answer to my problem. It was linked to our old way to generate the Jar with Ant.

The Ant jar task only put all .class from the bin directory generated by Eclipse into the archive. The problem is that `Eclipse seems to ignore all errors that may have in a class`. This is why the ant jar task worked. So, in fact, @HieryNomus you were right when you said in your comment that there is something else that the Ant jar task that compile the code.